# que significa != en python?

Tags: python

yo intente hacer este loop  ↓

```
si = ''
while si == 'si':
    print('colabora, quieres saber como seria tu nombre alreves?')
    si = input()

print('gracias por colaborar')
```

pero no funciono, me puse a investigar por internet y me di cuenta que utilizando "!=" en vez de "==" funcionaba, dejare el codigo que si funcion fue este ↓

```
si = ''
while si != 'si':
    print('colabora con lo feredico, quieres saber como seria tu nombre alreves?')
    si = input()

print('gracias por colaborar con los federicos')
```

el codigo funciona, mi pregunta es cual es la funcion de "!="? y que hace? y por que el codigo funciono con ese simbolo?

Comment: `!=` es la negación de la igualdad ( `==`)  o sea "distinto".

Comment: te funciona en principio, pero una vez coloques `"si"` en el input terminará el bucle. Esto pasa por que al inicio la variable `si` no contiene nada (cadena vacia).  Tu primer código es correcto solo debes de hacer la excepción para la primera interación. Solo es un error de tu lógica :D

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda en mi primer proyecto ♡

Answer (score 1):

Así como el operador `==` compara si dos valores son iguales, el operador `!=` compara si dos valores son distintos.

| valor1 | operador | valor2 | resultado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | == | 1 | true |
| 1 | != | 1 | false |
| 1 | == | 0 | false |
| 1 | != | 0 | true |

En tu código vemos que `si` la inicializas con un valor vacío;

```py
si = ''
```

Por eso en tu ciclo while al comparar `si = 'si'` el ciclo se detiene. Y al momento de hacer `si != 'si'` este empieza a correr porque efectivamente `''` es distinto que `'si'`.

```py
while si != 'si':
    print('colabora con lo feredico, quieres saber como seria tu nombre alreves?')
    si = input()

print('gracias por colaborar con los federicos')
```

El asunto aquí es que cuando escribas **si** cuando te lo pida el programa, este se detendrá, a menos que escribas **sí** con acento en la **i** ya que esto también es distinto a **si** sin acento.

Para evitar esto inicializa correctamente tu variable `si`

```py
si = 'si'
while si == 'si':
    print('colabora con lo feredico, quieres saber como seria tu nombre alreves?')
    si = input()

print('gracias por colaborar con los federicos')
```

Comment: muchas gracias eres un genio ♡ me gustria ser tan inteligente y con tanta experiencia como tu algun dia

Comment: @Breiner con esfuerzo y estudio dentro de poco lo lograrás. Hay algunas cosas que no importa que lenguaje uses, el uso es le mismo; es el caso de estos operadores. Conforme vayas avanzando te darás cuenta de esto y muchas otras cosas. Si la respuesta te ayudó, por favor acéptala como  correcta para que tu pregunta aparezca como solucionada